# invalid object name sql exception for table name in c#

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

I wrote this code, but it doesn't work. Gives Invalid object name 'Inventory'`.  Any Suggestion?

```
 using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            cn.ConnectionString =
            @"Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
            "Initial Catalog=AutoLot";
            cn.Open();
            string strSQL = "Select * From Inventory";
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cn);
            // Obtain a data reader a la ExecuteReader().
            using (SqlDataReader mydatareader = mycommand.ExecuteReader())
            {}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear - your database doesn't contain the table `Inventory`. *Does* the `AutoLot` database contain a table named `Inventory`? *Do* you have permission to read from it?

Comment: Also are you sure this `Inventory` table inside of default schema?

Comment: What **schema** is the `Inventory` table in? is it `dbo.Inventory`? or...?

Comment: It's suspect that the error message has an equal sign before the name of the table (`=Inventory`) - did you *really* copy and paste your code exactly? Or did you try to reproduce what you *think* your code says?

Comment: Also: is it *identical casing* ? Whether or not SQL Server is case sensitive is a configuration setting; the best practice is to always get it right, even if it is going to be insensitive

Comment: (edited) identifiers in a SQL-Server are 3-part: `[database].[schema].[object]`. `AutoLot.dbo.Inventory` is completely separate to `AutoLot.Soraya.Inventory`. If not specified explicitly, first the *current user's* schema is checked, then `dbo`. So if the Windows user is `MyApp`, and the object is `Soraya.Inventory`, then **it doesn't exist** in terms of resolution. `MyApp.Inventory` would be found, or `dbo.Inventory` would be found

Comment: @Jamiec hah, I think I've just understood your comment - yes, I typo'd; I'm going to leave my comment above, though, as it may help the OP

Comment: Im glad we cleared that one up (we did, right?)

Comment: @Jamiec yeah, it was my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in Database Inventory table is present or not and if Present then both name should be same

Comment: it present and also same.

Comment: check twice it's present same db which you used in code?

Comment: and critically: which schema; if it doesn't show as `dbo`, it is probably wrong for most application scenarios (unless you know what you are doing with schemas)

Answer (score 0):

If you've checked all your database settings, access rights and table definitions and still cannot get rid of that error?

It's because ASP.net *cannot understand* your SQL query - as shocking as that may sound.

I had the same problem, with `UPDATE` statements wanting to use `aliases` and not the usually expected `dbo.myTable` name definitions.

The simplest way to avoid this situation, where asp.net just doesn't parse SQL like SQL Server would (!!), is to place the code into a `Stored Procedure`.

This was my SQL directly from SQL Server 2005 and it worked perfectly as is...

```
UPDATE tsa
SET tsa.ActionComplete = @ActionComplete,
    tsa.CompleteDate = GETDATE(),
    tsa.Notes = @ActionNotes
FROM blahblah
WHERE blahblah
```

But for what ever reason, the ASP.net parser inside the `SqlDataSource` control could not make sense of it (even though it ran perfectly inside the GUI's *Test Query* feature!).

I was getting

> invalid object name in 'tsa'

So I placed the lot inside a Stored Procedure...

```
USE [mydatabase];
GO
SET  ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET  QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTETupdateActions]
    @StudentID VARCHAR(10),
    @ActionComplete INT = 0,
    @ActionNotes VARCHAR(MAX),
    @TETmeetingID INT,
    @WeekNo INT,
    @TETID INT,
    @TETdate DATETIME,
    @ActionItem VARCHAR(MAX)
    WITH
    EXEC AS CALLER AS
UPDATE tsa
SET tsa.ActionComplete = @ActionComplete,
    tsa.CompleteDate = GETDATE(),
    tsa.Notes = @ActionNotes
FROM blahblah
WHERE blahblah
GO
```

And voila! No more errors! Why? Because the parsing of the SQL is done inside SQL Server not ASP.net!